# Plugin Repostitory Questions

Tags: plugins, hosting

Hei,

i've been developing a few plugins over the last few weeks that i want to share, soon, such as:

- a 'helper'-plugin, that eases the creation of standard option pages
- a photo contest manager
- a subcription signup manager (a rewrite of 'user role subscriptions' by Byrd)
- a basic affiliate ad campain manager with referral tracking

Since im a lazy c*** i'm wondering if there's a necessity to setup my own site properly (which i have, but it still shows the ads from the hosting company ;-) ) or if using the SVN hosting offered by Wordpress Plugins gives me all i need?

Also, what are the licensing policies when hosting on Wordpress Plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins have to be licensed under the GPL and no, you don't have to set up your own site for them.

More info here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/